# If+can’t be if+won’t be able to

Tags: phrase-choice

Which one is the better choice in the following sentences and why?

1. If you **can’t /won’t  be able to** achieve it, don’t give out hope.
2. If it **can’t/won’t be able to** cure my pain, I won’t take the pill.
3. If you **can’t/won’t be able to** pay it back, don’t borrow money. Ok

Here's my thought

Can't: The inability to do something in the future is revealed first, as in "If you can't fulfill it, don't promise your children anything."

Won't be able to: The inability takes place after another action in the future, as in "If you won't be able to fulfill it, don't promise your children anything."

Comment: It depends what you are trying to say. _Can't (cannot)_ refers to the present, _won't (will not) be able to_ refers to the future.

Comment: @KateBunting Not in conditional protases --> "If you can't come tomorrow, ..." etc.

Comment: "won't be able to" is a milder expression.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is meant by _don't give out hope_. Either tense would work for (2). _Won't be able_ works best for (3) (you borrow money because you don't have enough _now_, but when the time comes to repay the debt you hope that you _will be able_ to do so.)

Comment: What's the difference between "can't" and "won't be able to" in this sentence?

Here's my thought

Can't: The inability to do something in the future is revealed first, as in "If you can't fulfill it, don't promise your children anything."

Won't be able to: The inability takes place after another action in the future, as in "If you won't be able to fulfill it, don't promise your children anything."

Comment: I can't do it now. I won't be able to do it later. If you are not able or can't fulfill it now, don't promise your children anything. Let's say it was a meeting: Will you be able to attend that meeting? Answer no: No, I will not be able to, but **if I am able to [or can]**, I **will tell you**. will/won't be able is not used after if.

Comment: We don't say: If you won't be able and If you will be able. The will/won't is used in the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

**to be able** to do something can be rendered with the verb **can**.

If you **aren't able** to achieve that goal, don't worry. [present]
If you *can't achieve* that, don't worry.[present]

If you can't pay it back, don't worry.

These are conditional sentences and will is not used after if.

If he goes, I will see him. [for example]

The future is **will be able** but is not used after if.
I **will be able** to pay it back next week.

If he **is able** to pay it back, I hope he **will do so** soon.

[Generally, a pill stops pain. We don't say to cure pain.] :)

[Note: the past tense is was able or could]